# PHP Class example

Tags: php

Can anyone help me with php classes example. I have to make class "information" that has information about users: id, email, password, first name, last name, phone.

Also, class  must have a method to print all the user data on the output.

Comment: Read, read, read : http://fr2.php.net/language.oop5.php

Comment: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Objects-Patterns-Practice-Matt-Zandstra/dp/1430260319/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1393410657&sr=1-1&keywords=php+objects+patterns+and+practice : I keep a paperback copy of this by my PC

Answer (score 3):

It's really simple skeleton, because you didn't try anything, so just for you to have idea how it works...

```
class User
{
   private $id;
   private $email;
   // ...

   public function __construct($id, $email...)
   {
      $this->id = $id;
      $this->email = $email;
      // ...
   }

   public function printAll()
   {
      return $this->id . ' ' . $this->email;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you reading this: http://codular.com/introducing-php-classes and then come back with any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a PHP class:

```
class DBIGenerator{
    private $table;
    private $name;
    private $path;
    public function __construct($table,$name='default_file.php',
            $path='DEFAULTPATH/'){
        $this->table=$table;
        $this->name=$name;
        $this->path=$path;
    }
    public function generate(){
        // build class header
        $str='<?php class '.$this->name.'{';
        if(!$result=mysql_query('SHOW COLUMNS FROM '.$this->table)){
            throw new Exception('Failed to run query');
        }
        // build data member declaration
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)<1){
            throw new Exception('Not available columns in table');
        }
        $methods='';
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            $str.='private $'.$row['Field'].'=\'\';';
            $methods.='public function set'.$row['Field'].'($'.$row
                 ['Field'].'){$this->'.$row['Field'].'=$'.$row
                 ['Field'].';}';
            $methods.='public function get'.$row['Field'].'(){return 
                 $this->'.$row['Field'].';}';
            // store field names in array
            $fields[]=$row['Field'];
        }
         // build empty constructor
        $str.='public function __construct(){}';
         // build modifiers and accessors
        $str.=$methods;
         // build load() method
        $str.='public function load(){$r=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM
                 '.$this->table.' WHERE id=\'$this->id\'");';
        $str.='return mysql_fetch_array($r,MYSQL_ASSOC);}';
        // build submit() method
        $str.='public function submit(){mysql_query("INSERT INTO '.$this-
                 >table.' SET ';
        foreach($fields as $field){
            $str.=($field!='id')?$field.'=\'$this->'.$field.'\',':'';
        }
        $str.='");$this->id=mysql_insert_id();';
        $str=preg_replace("/,\"/","\"",$str).'}';
        // build update() method
        $str.='public function update(){mysql_query("UPDATE '.$this-
                 >table.' SET ';
        foreach($fields as $field){
            $str.=($field!='id')?$field.'=\'$this->'.$field.'\',':'';
        }
        $str=preg_replace("/,$/","",$str);
        $str.=' WHERE id=\'$this->id\'");}';
        // build delete() method
        $str.='public function delete(){mysql_query("DELETE FROM '.
                 $this->table.' WHERE id=\'$this->id\'");}';
        $str.='}?>';
        // open or create class file
        if(!$fp=fopen($this->path.$this->name.'.php','w')){
            throw new Exception('Failed to create class file');
        }
        // lock class file
        if(!flock($fp,LOCK_EX)){
            throw new Exception('Unable to lock class file');
        }
        // write class code to file
        if(!fwrite($fp,$str)){
            throw new Exception('Error writing to class file');
        }
        flock($fp,LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fp);
        // delete temporary variables
        unset($fp,$str,$row,$fields,$field,$methods);
    }
    public function getObject(){
        // check if class file exists
        if(!file_exists($this->path.$this->name.'.php')){
            throw new Exception('Failed to include class file');
        }
        require_once($this->path.$this->name.'.php');
        // create data access object
        return new $this->name;
    }
}
```

Read more at http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Building-ObjectOriented-Database-Interfaces-in-PHP-Updating-the-Application-to-PHP-5/1/#Czocu1kMhhuTvg2e.99

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the snippet below as a basic way to implementing as expressed:

```
<?php
class information
{
    public $id    = 1;
    public $email = "mail@mail.com";
    public $pw    = "A2D7DFEA88AC88"; //Don't forget, PW are usually hashed ;)
    public function id() {
        echo $this->id;
    }
    public function email() {
        echo $this->email;
    }
    public function pw() {
        echo $this->pw;
    }
}
$test = new information();
$test->id;
?>
```